# Десериализация subclass. Из Json в Java

Tags: gson, java

Есть класс Message - предок и класс MessageHistory - наследник. Как десериализовать наследника ? Использую библиотеку - GSON.

```
public class Message {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("date")
    private long date;
    @SerializedName("out")
    private int out;
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    private int userId;

    public Message(int id, long date, int userId, int out) {
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.out = out;
    }
}

public class MessageHistory extends Message {
    @SerializedName("from_id")
     private int fromId;
     public MessageHistory(int id, long date, int userId, int out, int fromId) {
        super(id, date, userId, out);
        this.fromId = fromId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Привет.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    MessageHistory src = new MessageHistory(1, 102, 22, 1, 23);
    String s = gson.toJson(src) // {"from_id":23,"id":1,"date":102,"out":1,"user_id":22}
    MessageHistory messageHistory = gson.fromJson(s, MessageHistory.class); // восстанавливает объект обратно   
}
```